# Hyperlink Error on Concrete 8.2.0 & Windows Server 2012

Tags: caching, windows-server-2012-r2, concrete, concrete5-8.x

Currently having issues with hyperlinks:  Throughout the day hyperlinks will not work because www is not added to the URL and then randomly 20-30 minutes later the issue will be fixed.

My Concrete Environment:

```
Core Version - 8.2.0
Version Installed - 8.2.0
Database Version - 20170711151953
```

concrete5 Cache Settings

```
Block Cache - On
Overrides Cache - On
Full Page Caching - On - If blocks on the particular page allow it.
Full Page Cache Lifetime - Every 6 hours (default setting).
```

Server Software

```
Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

Server API

```
cgi-fcgi
```

PHP Version

```
7.1.8
```

PHP Extensions

```
bcmath, calendar, cgi-fcgi, Core, ctype, curl, date, dom, fileinfo, filter, gd, hash, iconv, intl, json, ldap, libxml, mbstring, mcrypt, mysqli, mysqlnd, odbc, openssl, pcre, PDO, pdo_mysql, Phar, readline, Reflection, session, SimpleXML, SPL, standard, tokenizer, wddx, wincache, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter, zip, zlib
```

PHP Settings

```
max_execution_time - 10240
log_errors_max_len - 1024
max_file_uploads - 500
max_input_nesting_level - 64
max_input_time - 60
max_input_vars - 1000
memory_limit - 4096M
post_max_size - 1000M
sql.safe_mode - Off
upload_max_filesize - 1000M
ldap.max_links - Unlimited
mysqli.max_links - Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent - Unlimited
odbc.max_links - Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent - Unlimited
pcre.backtrack_limit - 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit - 100000
session.cache_limiter - no value
session.gc_maxlifetime - 7200
wincache.maxfilesize - 2048
wincache.ttlmax - 1200
```

Comment: Have you set canonical URLs in the Concrete5 settings ?  Dashboard -> System and settings -> SEO -> URLs  ( dashboard/system/seo/urls )... Be sure to check 'URL redirect' . Setting the basic URL in Concrete5 will force a redirect to the domain URL you defined and search engines like it if you redirect to a preferred domain URL (either with or without www) .

Comment: I did not.  The puzzling thing to me is why does it sometimes add www and 20-30 minutes later it does not?

Comment: I am having IT make sure that both susd.org and www.susd.org work, but I still need to figure out why Concrete is randomly not adding the www.   Now I did just try to add https://www.susd.org  as canonical and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: Another thing, if I am logged into Concrete, the links issues are not present, the www has been added to the link.